# Deploy dot net core website under specific directory and app pool

Tags: deployment, .net-core, teamcity, application-pool

I have the following problem(s). We are migrating our existing application to a dot net core app. Both apps need to run under the same domain name. This is possible as long as they both run under there own app pool.

My first question is, how can I deploy a dot net core application under a specific application pool.

My second question is, how can I deploy this dot net core app under a specific directory i.e. c:/inetpub/mainsite/dotnetcore/

Our old application runs under the mainsite directory and now I would like to run the dot net core app under the dotetcore directory.

For the record, I'm using TeamCity for deploying the sites.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can recall, TeamCity supports powershell.

Add **webadministration** module, and you'll get the support to complete any IIS-related task. For instance:

```
New-WebAppPool YourPoolName

New-WebApplication -Site "You Web Site" -PhysicalPath "c:\inetpub\mainsite\dotnetcore" -Name YourAppName -ApplicationPool YourPoolName
```

Comment: Hi Milan, thanks for responding. I already can create the physical path and application pool. My problem is how to deploy the dot net core site under the "dotnetcore" application pool. Whenever I deploy my new dot net core site will be installed under the "mainsite" application pool.

Comment: Is your deploy completely OTB TeamCity, or are you using custom scripts?

Comment: Can you post your deploy script?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.

I have fixed my problem by assigning the website to the specific application pool with powershell.

Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\Sites\$webName\mvc" -name "applicationPool" -value "$mvcWebName"

This will assign the mvc site to run under the correct application pool.